# New to Swift (and programming in general). Why is my code calling the wrong action?

Tags: swift

I'm a total newbie, so pardon me if this is an annoying question. I am just practicing and am wondering why this code is printing "Almost perfect. Give it another try!" when it should be printing "Well, you got one correct". Any help would be much appreciated

```
var subjectOne = true
var subjectTwo = false
var subjectThree: Int = 5
func shout(subjectOne: Bool, subjectTwo: Bool, subjectThree: Int){
    if subjectOne && subjectTwo && subjectThree >= 25{
        print("HIGH SCORE!")
    }
    else if subjectOne || subjectTwo && subjectThree >= 10{
        print("Almost perfect. Give it another try!")
    }
    else if subjectOne && subjectTwo && subjectThree >= 10{
        print("There ya' go!")
    }else if !subjectOne && !subjectTwo && subjectThree >= 10{
        print("Well, you got a high enough number at least!")
    }else if subjectOne || subjectTwo && subjectThree < 10{
        print("Well, you got one correct")
    }else if !subjectOne && !subjectTwo && subjectThree < 10{
        print("You fail at life!")
    }else if subjectOne || subjectTwo && subjectThree >= 25{
        print("Almost a high score. Keep going, you got this!")
    }
}
shout(subjectOne: subjectOne, subjectTwo: subjectTwo, subjectThree: subjectThree)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your first else if clause is evaluating to true due to order of operations:

```swift
else if subjectOne || subjectTwo && subjectThree >= 10
```

evaluates from left to right, so your code first checks if `subjectOne` is true. Because it is indeed true, and an `||` (or) comes next, your code no longer needs to evaluate the rest of the expression because it already evaluates as true.

You might have meant to write that clause this way instead:

```swift
else if (subjectOne || subjectTwo) && subjectThree >= 10
```

This would evaluate to false because thanks to the parenthesis, your code knows that it must evaluate both sides of the expression (subjectOne or subjectTwo) AND subjectThree must be greater than or equal to ten.

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thank you so much. Not only did that solve this specific problem, you helped me learn!

Comment: To the OP: When in doubt, add parentheses to complex logic expressions to make it clear how to to interpret them.

Comment: @DuncanC thank you! That should help me along my journey.